# Indivudual roles for AWS credentials for AWS Cognito users from a User-Pool

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-polly

I am trying to do the following:

1. Establish a Cognito User Pool to manage sign-in/up/etc...
2. Assign individual roles to users
3. Obtain AWS credentials for the user which assume the roles defined for that particular user

To add more background: the goal using AWS/Cognito/Policies encompasses following aims (at user level):

- Prevent misusage of AWS resources without valid entitlement
- Offload the fine Grained control on what can be done with the costly AWS resources from the App to AWS (TTS, TTS Neural Voices, Quotas, ...)
- Offer options for further App functionalities based on AWS Services but limit the risk of them being used freely with an hacked App and access keys
- Eventually billing on usage

Clearly I haven't found the canonical way/place for these tasks, allthough AWS policies on a user level seem to be the right place. Because leaked credentials of a user could be blocked not impacting the rest of the pool.

**For 1. this is done.**

Currently I can Sign-in/-ou with the Userpool:

```
    AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient provider = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(new Amazon.Runtime.AnonymousAWSCredentials());
                    
    CognitoUserPool userPool    = new CognitoUserPool("eu-central-1_XXXXXXXX", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", provider);
    CognitoUser user            = new CognitoUser("Username", "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy", userPool, provider);
    
                    
    //
    // Authenticate User to AWS Cognito User Pool
    //
    InitiateSrpAuthRequest authRequest = new InitiateSrpAuthRequest()
    {
        Password = "PWD"
    };
    
    AuthFlowResponse authResponse = await user.StartWithSrpAuthAsync(authRequest).ConfigureAwait(false);
    
    // Print Token
    MessageBox.Show($"Token is : {authResponse.AuthenticationResult.AccessToken}");
```

For 2. I can have roles assigned to groups and the users of the user pool assigned to the groups.

For 3. This is where I am heading nowhere:

I can get temporary AWS credantials from the connected user as follows:

```
    //
    // Get Temporary Credentials for User
    //
    CognitoAWSCredentials awsCredentials = user.GetCognitoAWSCredentials("eu-central-1:zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz", RegionEndpoint.EUCentral1);
                    
    ImmutableCredentials iCredentials = awsCredentials.GetCredentials();
```

However. the credentials the user now has, are the credentials that are set to the Identity Pool, the usergroup is linked to for authenticated users. So any user connecting to that pool will have the same roles with these AWS credentials.

I cannot find any decent documentation or example showing what are the steps so to assign to **each** user individual roles, nor how to implement and control how users can assume other roles. Hence leave the identity pool without any privileges and let the users once connected retrieve the proper rights.

The groups assigned to the user in cognito user pool seem to have no effect on the roles attributed to the AWS credentials.

Also, for a service like AWS Polly, I could not find a way to use the Access Token of the user, returned during sign-in, which should contain the roles according to the users groups membership.

To stay with Polly this is the test code to get the speech:

```
    //
    // Create a client for the authenticated user
    //
    IAmazonPolly client = new AmazonPollyClient(iCredentials.AccessKey, iCredentials.SecretKey, iCredentials.Token, RegionEndpoint.EUCentral1);
    
    //
    // Use Polly client to generate speech
    //
    SynthesizeSpeechRequest synthesizeSpeechRequest = new SynthesizeSpeechRequest()
    {
        Engine = voice.HasModeNeural() ? Engine.Neural : Engine.Standard, // Try to use Neural engine
        OutputFormat = OutputFormat.Mp3,
        VoiceId = new VoiceId(voice.GetName()),
        Text = sText,
    };
    
    // Fetch Audio
    try
    {
        SynthesizeSpeechResponse synthesizeSpeechResponse = await client.SynthesizeSpeechAsync(synthesizeSpeechRequest);
    
        return synthesizeSpeechResponse;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

Comment: See following : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/role-based-access-control.html?force_isolation=true

Comment: Can you explain what is the problem you are trying to solve. Why does each user needs its own role?

Comment: @VikramS: Assume an application where users can opt-in for various paid services. They have credentials to login witht the application. Then depending on the subscruiptions they opt for, they get the right to access the AWS ressources or not. Well that is for the base Idea. I am still unsure how to implement this in AWS environment though. But the above aproach seems to match the description of the services. Sorry if I missed something obvious, but I had no luck reading trough docs and posts...

Comment: @jdweng: thank you. I'll check that out, headlines seem to go the right way. Maybe I am to naiv believing there is a clear walk-trough tutorial wich code examples to setup this functionality and reading (and understanding) AWS books is the long way to go :)

Comment: Do these paid-for services map 1:1 onto AWS services? Probably not, I would guess. Are you intending to share temporary AWS credentials to the users of your app?

Comment: Good point. Curently yes, but you make a point here. As said, I'm still exploring that ecosystem. Ideally, to stay with Polly, I'd like to not only avoid unlegit access to the AWS resources (which could also be done in a hackable App), but prevent that a leaked Account is misused to cause huge costs. Of course, only with a subscription full access would be granted or partial (e.g. Neural voices). I guess I will reformulate the question to clarify the intention.